# want to stop load the script for IE in a particular page by code

Tags: php, javascript

I created a website in that every page is working fine in every browser but ONLY one page(form Page) in IE is taking too much time for loading and the error I get is that IE is running a long script and is not responding.

I found a solution for this that in IE under the tool section I have to disable the script option and it works also but its not possible to tell every user to follow this solution, so I wanted to know is there any script or code with the help of which I can disable the script ONLY For this FORM PAGE in IE only for every user dynamically(I created a separate template for this form)

Thanks in advance.......

Comment: The best thing to do is identify the script that is taking long time and try to tweak it. Disabling the script in one page for a selective user is not an solution. It's asking for more problem.

Answer (score 0):

How about following..

```
<script>
    if( /* Browser checks */ )
        document.write( '<script src="scripts.js"></script>' );
</script>
```

If all your scripts are in one place, or at least not embedded all over the page, perhaps you should include them with JavaScript after checking the browser:

This is one scenario which illustrates why keeping your code http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself and all in one place is important.

For detecting browsers, check out http://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html, but note the link to their Object detection page instead if that's more useful for your use case. http://yepnopejs.com/ is useful for the latter, which is part of Modernizr.

Credits: [Disabling JS from within Website for specific browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6669292/disabling-js-from-within-website-for-specific-browsers)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use IE conditional comments:

```
<![if !IE]>
<script>
    // your non IE script here.
</script>
<![endif]>
```

For more info see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512(v=vs.85).aspx

---

### Additional explanation:

A note on how conditional comments work.

Conditional comments is an IE specific feature to expose or hide portions of content (not necessarily script) depending on IE versions or if the browser is non IE. For example:

```
<![if !IE]>
    Hello non IE
<![endif]>
```

Will print `Hello non IE` on non IE browsers and nothing at all on IE. It is only an IF statement. It is not a magic way to erase content. For example:

```
Hello non IE
<![if !IE]>
    Hello non IE
<![endif]>
```

will print:

```
Hello non IE
```

on IE and:

```
Hello non IE
Hello non IE
```

on non IE browsers. It does not delete the previous text. It merely hides the text inside it from IE.

As such, to exclude a script form IE you need to do this:

```
<![if !IE]>
<script src="non_ie_compatible_script.js">
<![endif]>
```

**NOT** this:

```
<script src="non_ie_compatible_script.js">

<![if !IE]>
<script src="non_ie_compatible_script.js">
<![endif]>
```

If you have no access to the original line that includes the script then there is nothing you can do.

If you have access to the script then you can use the other solutions posted on this page. But as you mentioned in your OP you don't have access to the script either so none of the solutions here will work. In fact, unless you have access to the server itself or some proxy that sits in front of the server (in which case you can intercept the entire page and delete the script inclusion tag before it's delivered to the browser) there is no solution to your problem.

Your best bet may in fact not be a coding solution but a human solution: talk to the owner/maintainer of the script or the owner/maintainer of your website and ask them to provide you with a way to turn off the script on specific pages.

Or do what @karthick suggests and debug your code instead of trying to disable the third party script.

Comment: Hi Slebetman,I want to say that I don't have script for this page, if this was the case I would have also done the same but but these scripts about which I am talking about is getting loaded for all the pages by default, so for this page also those script is coming............

Comment: That comment is an HTML comment. Do you not also have access to the HTML source?

Comment: Hi Slebetman, <br /> I already tried with the trick you told but still those Java Scripts are loading in IE and due to this, in other browser these scripts are running more than once. <br/> I think if we will use the script stopping code only for IE it will be much more useful, something like this -> <br/> <!--[if IE]>
// code for stopping the script
<![endif]-->

Comment: Since you don't have access to the javascript, there is no way to write another piece of javascript outside the included file to stop the code from running. So there is no such thing as code that stops the code. From your comments it appears that you're doing the IF somewhere other from where the js file is included into the page (code in other browsers running a second time). That's too late already. You need to put the IF around where the file is sourced in the first place. If it's in a template wrapper that you don't have access to then there is no solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try

http://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html

or

alert(navigator.appName);